# Is there a way to read both form data and uploaded file (multipart/form-data) using flask

Tags: rest, http, flask

I am exposing a flask api with content-type=multipart/form-data which takes both json and .zip file as input. When I try to read, I am able get the zip file. however, I am not able to read the json file. I tried several things but none them have the json data. Is this even supported ?

I am using flask restplus parser to read the file contents using "werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage", whereas to get the json I have used different options given below , none worked
->request.form

->dict(request.form)

->request.files.get_json(force=True)

->api.payload

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage, ImmutableMultiDict


parser= api.parser()
parser.add_argument('opc-retry-token', location='headers',required='true')

parser.add_argument('file', location='files', type=FileStorage, required=True)

def init(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        token = args['opc-retry-token']
        self.token=token
        self.args=args
        logger.info(args) 

# above log  gives {'opc-retry-token': '1234', 'file': <FileStorage:         


@ns.route('/prepare')
@api.expect(parser)
class OICPrepare(Resource):

    @api.expect(oic_prepare)
    def post(self):

        init(self)
        logger.info(request.form)
# above log gives 'None'
        data = dict(request.form)
        logger.info(data)
# above log gives ImmutableMultiDict([])

        logger.info(request.files.get_json(force=True))
#above log gives {}       
        upload_file = self.args['file']
        upload_file.save('/oic_admin/wallet.zip')
#above save command does the zip file properly
```

I am expecting both zip file and json to be read by flask api.

Comment: From what I understand from [the documentation](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parsing.html#file-upload), Flask RESTPlus supports uploading only one file at a time. Pure Flask solution supports multiple files though, see [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.files).

Comment: the json is submitted as formdata. like {"data":{"a":"string"},{"b":"string"}}